# Is it posible to deploy complete Production org to an Sandbox?

Tags: deployment, integration, full-sandbox

we are planning to deploy our complete Production org to an Test Sandbox, but we can't find any guidelines how to do it. Where must we think of what are the pitfalls if we are doing this.

Is there any online info about this?

Comment: Why is this tagged with "azure"? Do you have a license enabling you to create a [Full Sandbox](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.create_test_instance.htm&type=5)? Have you had a look at the documentation of this type of Sandbox?

Answer (score 1):

The approach that comes to mind is that you need to create a [Full Copy sandbox](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.data_sandbox_create.htm&type=5).  This will grab all of your Metadata and Data from Production.   Before you go and create the full copy sandbox, I recommend that you start here: Define a Development Org Strategy to support your dev process (at the bottom), [Sandbox Types and Templates](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.create_test_instance.htm&type=5) And [DevOps](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/05/gitlab-salesforce-devops-made-easy).

There are  trailheads that address DevOps, Sandboxes and sfdx cli - so you should spend time going through them to fully understand the concepts and to get additional hands on experience.

The downside of partial copy sandboxes is that you have limited data And you don't want to create a new Partial Copy Sandbox for every release.

Full Copy sandboxes are limited (based on your Salesforce Licensing) and are typically used for UAT/QA & testing (performance testing, stress testing).  The refresh interval is a drawback for development.

Lastly, there are limitations on the number of Sandboxes that you can create.  So it's important for you/team to layout the Sandboxes and tie them back to your development process (i.e. - Dev (Dev or Dev Pro) -> Test (Partial)-> UAT/QA (Full) -> Prod)

Comment: also -- fullcopy sandboxes have a copy of PROD data which might be sensitive (PII, trade secrets, etc.)